# How to make apt-get accept new config files in an unattended install of debian from Repo

Tags: software-installation, apt, aptitude

I am writing a script for a unattended install of a package that is in our repo, it is a software package with one of Debian's marked config files. 
Is there any option that I can pass to `apt-get`/`aptitude` so that it accepts the new config files?

Basically I need an `apt`/`aptitude` equivalent of  `dpkg --force-confnew`

I need to answer the following question posed while `apt-get` is installing with a Y

---

Configuration file ``/opt/application/conf/XXX.conf`'

```
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.

What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : background this process to examine the 

The default action is to keep your current version.
```

---

Additional Info:

Also, I am passing the `sudo` password in a pipe to execute the command

```
echo "mysudopass"|sudo -S apt-get mypackage
```

This is flagging an error in installation when the installation is at the config interactive phase.

I am on Ubuntu 10.04
apt version:  apt 0.7.25.3

**Why I cannot use `dpkg`: These Debians are to be installed from Repo and I don't have local Debians on my machine**

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/48724/100-non-interactive-debian-dist-upgrade

Answer (score 31):

You can pass `dpkg` parameters to `apt-get` like this

```
apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew install pkgname1 pkgname2 ...
```

With `--force-confdef` if old config files still exist, they won't get overridden. So you probably won't use it, I'm just documenting it for others.

`sudo` will not ask for a password if you negate the authenticate option for the user  or add the `NOPASSWD` tag in the specific entry. e.g.

```
someuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try the following:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y install whatever-2
```

But note that this has implications, like empty default passwords (maybe you'd like some deployment/config tool like puppet, chef, fabric...?).

See [sudoers(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) about how to allow password-less `sudo` invocations.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, you may also have to set the environment [UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW=1](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ucf/ucf.1.en.html#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES).

E.g. openssh in debian stretch uses ucf (not debconf) in it's `openssh-server/openssh-7.4p1/debian/openssh-server.postinst` to ask about the config file. (You can see the `openssh-server.postinst` by using `dget` against http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssh/openssh_7.4p1-10+deb9u4.dsc)

We've had to use all the tricks on this page in addition to being liberal users of [debconf preseeding](https://www.google.com/search?q=debconf+preseeding).

We did however stop just short of `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` because we want to know if we missed something (that could be important). Our use case is an operator starting the operation. The upgrade is expected to be non-interactive, but the operator is present if something goes wrong and a dialog presents itself. Your situation may be different.

But `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is your proverbial sledgehammer.

Just beware: Setting `-o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew` and/or `UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW=1` means that *all* config files from installed packages revert to the upstream ones. So e.g. in the case of `openssh-server`, your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` will be reset to factory settings. And e.g. `PermitRootLogin=yes` will be removed. But of course you don't use that, so you'll be fine! ;-)

Comment: The default value of `PermitRootLogin` is `yes` though.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to what [forcefsck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22876) suggested I suggest you add this into APT settings so you are not required to add these hard-to-write options all the time. Also, this would be helpful for unattended upgrades if you have these setup.

Create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/71debconf` file to have the following content:

```
Dpkg::Options {
  "--force-confnew";
};
```

Note (from Geoff): this change would be a global change. If you have other packages on the system that you want to get unattended upgrades but have also manually configured, this would not be the appropriate solution.

Comment: This may be a good option, however it's important to note that this would be a GLOBAL change.  If you have other packages on the system that you want to get unattended upgrades but have also configured, this would not be the appropriate solution.